# Increment elements ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

but with this code all checkbox elements have the same id...

```
var count;
var length = $('input[type=checkbox]').length
for(count=1;count<=length;count++){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('id',count)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Set elements ID using .prop() or .attr()

```
$(':checkbox').prop("id", function( i ){
    return i;
});
```

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wuseqe/2/edit?html,js,output)

### Set elements ID using .each()

```
$(':checkbox').each(function( i ){
    this.id = i;
});
```

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wuseqe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Both examples return:

```
<input id="0" type="checkbox">
<input id="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="2" type="checkbox">
<input id="3" type="checkbox">
```

if you want to start from 1 just use:

```
this.id = i+1;
```

Since numerical ID is not supported in non HTML5 (older) browsers, add any string **prefix** to the ID number like `"el"+ (i+1)`

Comment: Ids starting with integer is not valid markup. You should use a prefix.

Comment: @OptimusCrime In html5, this is valid ids

Comment: Even 0[1][2][3] is now a valid ID

Comment: @roXon: I know that, but since it is not specified that this is for HTML5 is should have a prefix to make sure it works in ALL cases.

Comment: @roasted: ^ don't you agree?

Comment: @OptimusCrime oh, I mentioned that in my answer, to avoid mistakes! thanks!

Comment: @OptimusCrime me i'm quite agree

Comment: @roXon: Although, I have to say, neat way to set the id. I'll keep this in mind for later.

Comment: @pouya a checkbox has no numbers... I don't get your thoughts

Comment: i want any `label` connect to a checkbox like this:   `<input type="checkbox" id="check1" /><label for="check1">B</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><label for="check2">I</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3" /><label for="check3">U</label>`

Comment: Yes thanks, you're very talented...., How can I look like you want to be a professional??

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('id', function(i) {
     return ++i;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` instead:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i) {
    // i is the 0-based index of this element in the matched set
    $(this).prop('id', i); 
});
```

Comment: `id` is a property, not an attribute; `.prop()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jack That's an old debate but where is it stipulated than id is now a property no more an attribute? I can find any info on this.

Comment: @Jack BTW, i know id is both but have you any link?

Comment: @Jack - Or even better, just use `this.id` as in roXon's answer. Less code to write, less code to execute and (negligibly) faster as well.

Comment: @roasted I would suggest reading [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: Yes, `this.id` is of course the best =D it's a fair bit faster because you don't have to wrap `this` in a jQuery object first.

Comment: @Jack I have, but still id should be fixed (and are always string), so i cannot see any advantage to use prop() instead of attr(). "the property always represents the current state while the attribute corresponds to the default value"  Id should always stays as default value

Comment: @Jack - Yes, but unless you are doing it on a loop over a lot of items, the difference isn't even measurable i believe. But nonetheless `this.id` is the way to do i'd say.

Comment: @roasted I'd rather err on the safe side with these things :) to be fair, I would use neither and just reference the property directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through elements returned by selector and assign ids. *Numeric id is generally not considered a good practice* you prefix of postfix with some string.

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('id',"id_"+i)
 })
```

Comment: `id` is a property, not an attribute; `.prop()` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var count = 1;
   $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index,domobj) {
      $(domobj).prop("id",count++);
   });
});
```

use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) when your jquery is **1.6+**

use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) when your jquery is **1.6-**